# Can enableObjectReuse() cause data discrepency In Flink-SQL based job

Tags: apache-kafka, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Can `env.getConfig.enableObjectReuse()` cause data discrepancy In Flink-SQL based job where we don't have any custom type, serializer/deserializer ?

```
create table T1 (...) WITH ( 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka','topic' = 'T1', ...)
create table T2 (...) WITH ( 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka','topic' = 'T2', ...)
create table enrich (...) WITH ( 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka','topic' = 'enrich', ...)

insert into enrich 
select ... from T1 inner join T2 ...
```

and these SQL executed through
`tableEnv.executeSql(query)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `enableObjectReuse` is safe to use in pure SQL/Table jobs.